# method find javascript deep array object RN react native

Tags: javascript, object, react-native, find

Here is a part of my object

```
const category = {
    fr: {
        list: [
            {id: 1, label: 'coucou'},
            {id: 2, label: 'moi'},
            {id: 3, label: 'ici'},
            {id: 4, label: 'maintenant'},
            {id: 5, label: 'demain'},
]}}
const lang = fr;
const anyId = 3;
```

I don't know why when doing the following:

`const result = category[lang].list.find(item => item.id === anyId) console.log(result)`

Throws the following:

> // undefined category[lang].list.find(item => item.id === anyId) is not
>   a function, or just undefined

same result for .map or .filter

- `console.log(category)` returns no error
- `console.log(category[lang])` returns no error
- `console.log(category[lang].list)` returns no error

but anything else will return an error.
It drives me crazy, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `const lang = 'fr'` not lteral `fr`

By having `fr` not wrapped in quotes your code is expecting `fr` to have already been defined (hence the `undefined` error during run time) :-)

Comment: `is not a function, or just undefined` --> so is it the first or the second error? Is it undefined, but defined, just not a function??

Comment: `console.log(category[lang]) returns no error`, but what does it display?

Comment: Your code will work wrapping that `fr` with quotes, but you need to be sure is that what you want.  The variable `fr` here `const lang = fr;` is another declared variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use `const lang = "fr"` instead of `const lang = fr`, because `fr` is an undefined variable but `"fr"` is a string. So you'll get `category["fr"]` instead of `category[fr]`.

```js
const category = {
    fr: {
        list: [
            {id: 1, label: 'coucou'},
            {id: 2, label: 'moi'},
            {id: 3, label: 'ici'},
            {id: 4, label: 'maintenant'},
            {id: 5, label: 'demain'},
]}}
const lang = "fr";
const anyId = 3;

const result = category[lang].list.find(item => item.id === anyId)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I think this is not the problem

Comment: Well I think it is, because if you use "fr", the code works.

Comment: If that was the problem, the error would be `fr is not defined`

Comment: Well, run my snippet. If you use `"fr"`, it works. What else can I say

Comment: Of course it works, but this doesn't help.  Imagime that `fr` is a declared variable in another part of the code and cause that the OP is facing that problem.

Comment: You're right, we need more info. OP says `is not a function, or just undefined`, these are two very different errors. Is it not a function, or is it completely undefined? `console.log(category[lang]) returns no error`, alright but what does it display? We don't know that. I'm waiting for these answers

Comment: I agree with that.

Comment: @JeremyThille it doesn't sorry for the '' missing it wasn't on the original problem, still have to give it a try on react native though, check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You want `category.fr` not just `fr`, as the variable `fr` does not exist.

Now that `lang` contains your `fr` object, you can simply do a `.find()` on `lang.list` as below:

```js
const category = {
    fr: {
        list: [
            {id: 1, label: 'coucou'},
            {id: 2, label: 'moi'},
            {id: 3, label: 'ici'},
            {id: 4, label: 'maintenant'},
            {id: 5, label: 'demain'},
]}}

// Fill param from a variable, or anything, as long as it's a string:
const param = 'fr';
// Use brackets here, as you want `category.fr` and not `category.param`:
const lang = category[param];
//Or you can simply use:
//const lang = category.fr; //If this is not a parameter, or user input

const anyId = 3;

console.log(lang);

console.log(lang.list.find(item => item.id === anyId));
```

Comment: And then, how do you get a parametric lang, if there's more than `fr`? Say, `en` or `de`?

Answer (score 0):

It works on mdn sandbox

```
const category = {
    fr: {
        list: [
            {id: 1, label: 'coucou'},
            {id: 2, label: 'ici'},
            {id: 3, label: 'demain'},
            {id: 4, label: 'matin'},
          ]
    }
};
var lang ='fr';
var catID = 3;
console.log(lang);
console.log(catID);
console.log(category);
console.log(category[lang]);
console.log(category[lang].list);
var found = category[lang].list.find(function(element) {
   return element.id === catID;
});

console.log(found.label); // demain
```

just add a return inside the callback function,
but it still doesn't work on react-native
so the problem remains